# New motherboard - activating Windows 10 free upgrade

Tags: windows, licensing

I had upgraded from Windows 8.0 (retail) to 8.1 to 10. Is there a guaranteed way of successfully activating Windows 10 after I change my motherboard?

I am prepared to reinstall Windows 8 and re-upgrade to Windows 10, but will that work?

Or even better, now that Windows 10 Setup accepts Windows 8 keys, will I be able to simply input my Windows 8 key to activate?

Answer (score 1):

Either way round will require you to ring Microsoft, as the new mobo will be considered a 'new computer'

Re-using your Windows 8 key is only possible if the key was previously registered to that computer - which it won't be as it will be 'new'.